# Copying values from one column that matches a ID to a new sheet by creating new columns for each values through EXCEL VBA

Tags: excel, vba, grouping, copying

I have a requirement where there is a group of values under one ID(this ID is unique for each group). I want the values of the group to be copied to a new sheet by creating new columns for each values through excel VBA.
say, this is my main sheet

```
ORDER NO.    BILL  ITEM
============================ 
12345        100       Pizza
12345        200       Choco
12345        300       Coffee
12345        400       Pizza1
12345        500       Drink
12456        600       Pizza
12456        700       Choco
12456        800       Pizza1
12360        900       Pizza
12360        1000      Choco
12360        1100      Coffee
```

I want the o/p like the one below:

```
ORDER NO. PIZZA PIZZA1 CHOCO COFFEE COFFEE1 DRINK 
===============================================================  
12345     100   400    200   300            500  
12456     600   800    700    
12360     900         1000   1100
```

I would like that the values present in the main sheet should be copied to a new workbook to the corresponding columns like 'PIZZA' values should be copied to a new workbook against the correct 'ORDER NO.' as in main sheet. Need a excel VBA to do this.Kindly help.

Comment: Please use code tags {} to format sample data. What have you got so far - where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a new workbook with sheets called Sheet1 and Sheet2 (names can be changed by changing constants in the code)
Add a main module and 3 Class modules (click Inser > Module and Insert Class Module in the VBA editor, Alt F11 to start)
Rename the class modules as follows: Bill, Item and Order

Add the following code to Class module Bill

```
Option Explicit

Public ID As String
Public ItemName As String
```

Add the folloing to Class module  Item

```
Option Explicit

Public Name As String
Public ColumnNumber As Long

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    ColumnNumber = 0
End Sub
```

Add the following code to Class Module Order

```
Option Explicit

Public Bills As Collection
Public ID As String

Public Sub AddBill(BillID As String, ItemName As String)
    Dim B As Bill

    Set B = New Bill
    B.ID = BillID
    B.ItemName = ItemName
    Bills.Add B
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set Bills = New Collection

End Sub
```

Add the following code to your main moodule

```
Option Explicit
Const ORDER_TXT As String = "Order No." 'text in the header cell for order number column
Const INPUT_SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
Const OUTPUT_SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet2"
Const FIRST_OUTPUT_COL As Long = 2
Const FIRST_OUTPUT_ROW As Long = 2


Dim Orders As Collection
Dim Items As Collection

Sub process_data()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim HeaderRow As Long
Dim HeaderCol As Long
Dim CurRow As Long
Dim CurOrder As Order
Dim CurItemCol As Long
Dim CurItem As Item
Dim CurBill As Bill

'Get Info from input sheet
CurItemCol = FIRST_OUTPUT_COL + 1
HeaderRow = 1
HeaderCol = 1
Set Orders = New Collection
Set Items = New Collection

If FindCell(ORDER_TXT, INPUT_SHEET_NAME, sh, HeaderRow, HeaderCol, False) Then
CurRow = HeaderRow + 1
Do While sh.Cells(CurRow, HeaderCol).Value <> ""
    Set CurOrder = GetOrder(sh.Cells(CurRow, HeaderCol).Value)
    If sh.Cells(CurRow, HeaderCol + 1).Value <> "" Then
        If sh.Cells(CurRow, HeaderCol + 2).Value <> "" Then
            Set CurItem = GetItem(sh.Cells(CurRow, HeaderCol + 2).Value)
            If CurItem.ColumnNumber = 0 Then
                'its a new item
                CurItem.ColumnNumber = CurItemCol
                CurItemCol = CurItemCol + 1
            End If
            'now add this bill to the order
            Call CurOrder.AddBill(sh.Cells(CurRow, HeaderCol + 1).Value, CurItem.Name)
        End If 'could add else with error message here
    End If
    CurRow = CurRow + 1
Loop

'now put data on output sheet
'find output sheet
For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If sh.Name = OUTPUT_SHEET_NAME Then Exit For
Next

'Add check here that we found the sheet

CurRow = FIRST_OUTPUT_ROW
'write headers
sh.Cells(CurRow, FIRST_OUTPUT_COL).Value = ORDER_TXT
For Each CurItem In Items
    sh.Cells(CurRow, CurItem.ColumnNumber).Value = CurItem.Name
Next
'Write Orders
For Each CurOrder In Orders
    CurRow = CurRow + 1
    sh.Cells(CurRow, FIRST_OUTPUT_COL).Value = CurOrder.ID
    For Each CurBill In CurOrder.Bills
        sh.Cells(CurRow, GetColumnNumber(CurBill.ItemName)).Value = CurBill.ID
    Next
Next

End If
End Sub
Function GetColumnNumber(ItemName As String) As Long
Dim I As Item

GetColumnNumber = 1 'default value
For Each I In Items
    If I.Name = ItemName Then
        GetColumnNumber = I.ColumnNumber
        Exit Function
    End If
Next
End Function
Function GetOrder(OrderID As String) As Order
Dim O As Order

For Each O In Orders
    If O.ID = OrderID Then
        Set GetOrder = O
        Exit Function
    End If
Next
'if we get here then we didn't find a matching order
Set O = New Order
Orders.Add O
O.ID = OrderID
Set GetOrder = O

End Function
Function GetItem(ItemName As String) As Item
Dim I As Item

For Each I In Items
    If I.Name = ItemName Then
        Set GetItem = I
        Exit Function
    End If
Next
'if we get here then we didn't find a matching Item
Set I = New Item
Items.Add I
I.Name = ItemName
Set GetItem = I

End Function
Function FindCell(CellText As String, SheetName As String, sh As Worksheet, row As Long, col As Long, SearchCaseSense As Boolean) As Boolean
Const GapLimit As Long = 10

'searches the named sheet column at a time, starting with the column and row specified in row and col
'gives up on each row if it finds GapLimit empty cells
'gives up on search if it finds do data un GapLimit columns

Dim RowFails As Long
Dim ColFails As Long
Dim firstrow As Long

FindCell = False
firstrow = row
ColFails = 0
RowFails = 0

'find sheet
For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If sh.Name = SheetName Then Exit For
Next

If sh.Name = SheetName Then
    Do 'search columns
        ColFails = ColFails + 1
        Do  'search column
            If sh.Cells(row, col).Value = "" Then
                RowFails = RowFails + 1
            Else
                If ((sh.Cells(row, col).Value = CellText And SearchCaseSense) Or (UCase(sh.Cells(row, col).Value) = UCase(CellText) And (Not SearchCaseSense))) Then
                    FindCell = True
                    Exit Function
                End If
                RowFails = 0
                ColFails = 0
            End If
            row = row + 1
        Loop While RowFails <= GapLimit
        col = col + 1
        row = firstrow
        RowFails = 0
    Loop While ColFails < GapLimit
End If
End Function
```

Run the routine process_data (Alt F8 from excel)

This program does not take account of multiple bills with the same items (e.g. Coffee) on the same order, only one bill will appear, I did not know how you wanted to handle that situation. The code needs checking and error handling routines to make it robust against invalid data, I have added a few comments as hints.

Hope this helps

Comment: That worked great :):) Thank you so much....amazing stuff. But is it possible to consider all the instances of an item i.e., if there are two 'Coffees'or 'Pizza' in one Order No., i need both the values of it updated in the neighbouring columns. if needed you can specify '4' columns for each item.so that i can get all the data and instances. Is that possible? I just need to have all the 'Items' in separate columns. we can assign certain no.of columns to each items, so that the items will fit into an one of those columns.

Comment: Yes I can do that, can you ask it as another question so that I can post the code to the answer please, as comments only allow limited number of chrs?

Comment: I am sorry for late reply. Surely I will do it tomorrow. Hope you can reply me. thanks a lot in advance. thank u so much.

Comment: Hi I have posted the question, you can search with my user ID.Please help me. THank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for a Pivot Table.  Put the Order No in the Row section, the Item in the Column section, and the Bill in the Values section.